What limits the number of photons in photonic quantum computing chips compared to optical table setups?
I've noticed that in 2024, photonic quantum computing experiments performed on optical tables compute using around 100-200 photons. However, photonic quantum chips tend to work with far fewer photons, often around 15, or even fewer than 10. What are the major technical challenges or physical limitations that prevent photonic quantum chips from scaling up to higher photon numbers, similar to optical table setups? Are these limitations mainly due to fabrication challenges, photon loss, noise, or other factors specific to chip-based platforms?
